# Azure When Uploading File, Throw an exception "The specified blob does not exist"

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

i develop an app via .net core. I use Azure Storage for my files. But sometimes code throws an expection: The specified blob does not exist.

This is how i start file upload process:

```
entity = FileUploadBusinessRule.UploadFile(entity, companyInformationEntityRequestDto.BusinessLicenseBase64,
                "BusinessLicenseUrl");

entity = FileUploadBusinessRule.UploadFile(entity, companyInformationEntityRequestDto.CompanyLogoBase64,
                "CompanyLogoUrl");
```

FileUploadBusinessRule.UploadFile:

```
public static class FileUploadBusinessRule
{
    public static T UploadFile<T>(T entity, string file, string propName)
    {
        IStorageService _storageService = DependencyContainerHelper.Container.Resolve<IStorageService>();

        Type t = entity.GetType();
        var propertyValue = t?.GetProperty(propName)?.GetValue(entity)?.ToString();


        if (!file.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            if (file.Contains("http://") || file.Contains("https://"))
                return entity;

            if (!propertyValue.IsNullOrEmpty())
                _storageService.DeleteBlobData(propertyValue);

            t?.GetProperty(propName)?.SetValue(entity, _storageService.UploadFileByBase64String(file));
        }
        else
        {
            if (!propertyValue.IsNullOrEmpty())
                _storageService.DeleteBlobData(propertyValue);
        }

        return entity;
    }
}
```

_storageService.UploadFileByBase64String:

```
public string UploadFileByBase64String(string strBase64)
    {
        var byteArray = strBase64.Base64ToByteArray();
        var mimeType = strBase64.GetMIMETypeFromBase64();
        var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "." + strBase64.GetExtensionFromBase64();
        return this.UploadFile(fileName, byteArray, mimeType);
    }
```

UploadFile:

```
public string UploadFile(string strFileName, byte[] fileData, string fileMimeType)
    {
        try
        {
            var _task = Task.Run(() => this.UploadFileToBlobAsync(strFileName, fileData, fileMimeType));
            _task.Wait();
            string fileUrl = _task.Result;
            return fileUrl;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
    }
```

UploadFileToBlobAsync:

```
private async Task<string> UploadFileToBlobAsync(string strFileName, byte[] fileData, string fileMimeType)
    {
        try
        {
            CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(accessKey);
            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            string strContainerName = "files";
            CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(strContainerName);
            string fileName = this.GenerateFileName(strFileName);
            if (await cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync())
            {
                await cloudBlobContainer.SetPermissionsAsync(new BlobContainerPermissions { PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Container });
            }

            if (fileName != null && fileData != null)
            {
                CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
                cloudBlockBlob.Properties.ContentType = fileMimeType;
                await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);
                return cloudBlockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
            }
            return "";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

When code execute first line (entity = FileUploadBusinessRul... blabla), app can successfully upload file. But when execute second line, it's throws an exception in this line:

```
if (await cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync())
```

I tried same files but it's throws an exception anyway. Also, even i wrapped try-catch block, app stops.

Comment: `The specified blob does not exist` You can try to use fiddler etc tool to capture the request and check which request cause 404 error.

Comment: Check if another app is deleting it?

Comment: When you say `await cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync()` is throwing exception, what is the exception? It can't be "blob does not exist" since you are doing container operation!

Comment: Side note: "even i wrapped try-catch block, app stops" - Looking at your try catch block, you are just rethrowing it, which is as good as not having it at all (rather worse since you are doing `throw ex` which would lose the stacktrace in upper layer)! Of course it does not help :)

Comment: Another side note: Why are you mixing async and non-async code? In UploadFile method, the way you are calling async code by Task.Run and Wait is somewhat quirky to be honest. You should either have async all the way or not at all (though not much reason to not to go with async). You can read more about async https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: Another side note (probably the last one :)): What is `_storageService.DeleteBlobData` doing in FileUploadBusinessRule class?

Comment: @HarshitaSingh-MSFT There is no app use the same cdn.

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT Exception is "The specified blob does not exist" at "await cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync()". Also, i know i'm throwing it back but there is a middleware for handle that, even an error occured, system must continue. But when this exception  throws, azure app service stops and re-run itself.

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT For Async and sync function, thank you for information, I will study that.

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT for "_storageService.DeleteBlobData in FileUploadBusinessRule", for example, your entity's imageUrl changed, i will delete previous blob and replace url the new one.

Comment: CloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync can never throw "The specified blob does not exist" exception since it's a container operation, not blob operation. I am sure there must be some gap in that interpretation. It might be from somewhere else. Please post the stacktrace after removing the empty `throw ex` catch blocks (since those will cause to lose full stacktrace.